# Create dictionary with N action parameters

Tags: c#

Lets assume we initialize a dictionary where we want to store our methods:

```
public Dictionary<string, Action<int>> Dic = Dictionary<string, Action<int>>;


public void one(int a) {};
public void two(int a, int b) {};
```

**Question**: Is there anyway to say that it can have either 1 or 2 ints as a parameter? Right now im doing this as a work-around:

```
public void one(int a, int b) {};
public void two(int a, int b) {};
```

Now both have two parameters even though the first one needs just 1.

Any solution?

Comment: why don't you use an array as one input? Or list?

Comment: Can you please show how are you going to use this dictionary? How you will know that Dic["foo"] will require only `a` parameter, and Dic["bar"] will need both?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I actually want to store my methods so that I can call them by string later...Just as you just showed

Comment: @Asperger exactly, so if `dict["foo"]` requires one param and `dict["bar"]` requires two - how do you know?

Comment: @Jamiec well Im going to document it. Hope I understand what you were asking.

Comment: It seems there is no way to solve this though. I probably have to stick with my work-around

Comment: @Asperger if you know beforehand - you dont need a dictionary to store your Actions. This is a bit of a circular argument. Perhaps provide more detail of *what youre trying to achieve* rather than *how you intend to achieve it*. (ie, this is an XY Problem)

Comment: Or maybe do as Taha said and use a list

Comment: @Asperger So callers just need to memorize what inputs return values of certain types?  That's going to be *extremely* hard to use, and as mentioned, means that you really shouldn't be using a dynamic data structure in the first place, if you're just going to have your callers hard coding the values.

Comment: Use vararg `params int[]` perhaps?

Comment: This problem is "clear" sign that your code design goes in the wrong way. Stop using those kind of workarounds and try to recognize where you can split logic up for more cleaner approach. If you show how you going to use this dictionary

Comment: As @Jamiec said, you need to be clearer on what exactly you're trying to achieve. What's the point of storing functions in a dictionary? Are you exposing it publicly? Why exactly wouldn't plain old public methods on a plain old class do the trick? What's the supposed advantage you get by storing functions in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the maximum number of parameters which will occur and artificially creating more arguments (an approach which could be jokingly called [de-schönfinkelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Sch%C3%B6nfinkel)) makes it necessary to know the maximum number of arguments beforehand (disregarding the fact that the [predefined delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386922(v=vs.110).aspx) support "only" up to 9 argument types); however, if by some other mechanism you will know the number of arguments anyway, you could just use

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

to store the delegates and cast them back to the desired type as follows.

```
((Action<int,int,int>)Dic["foo"])(1,2,3)
```

Comment: you cant store delegates as objects or am I wrong? doesnt work for me

Comment: @Jamiec but not dict.Add("Foo", fooBar);

Comment: @Asperger I dont follow - what is `fooBar`. Well it doesnt matter, if its *anything* it can be stored as an `object`. Everything is an `object`.

Comment: @Jamiec fooBar is a function pointer to a method inside the class.

Comment: Like essentially storing the reference to something like this: 
        public void fooBar(int x) {}

Comment: @Jamiec It wouldn't compile if it's a method group.  You could make it compile, but you'll need to explicitly convert it to a delegate first.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the arguments that your problems are best solved at the code design level - but that being said, I believe you can achieve what you want using `dynamic`:

```
static void Action(int a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}

static void Action(int a, int b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a + b);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, dynamic> Dic = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    Dic.Add("ActionA", new Action<int>(Action));
    Dic.Add("ActionB", new Action<int, int>(Action));
    Dic["ActionB"](4, 5);
}
```